# Action Bar for android < 3.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want use ActionBar for my application but i found it can't use for android < 3.0.
I found this https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar to solved my problem but I get error at

```
import com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar;
import com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar.Action;
import com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar.IntentAction;
```

Comment: What error? How did you include the files?

Comment: The import com.markupartist cannot be resolved .. I found this https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar ... I use code but i don't know to include lib :(

Answer (score 2):

Give [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) a try. I use it for one of my projects and after some reading of the docs and the samples it just worked. The samples are easy and straight forward, you should be able to extract what you need from them.

To see what it's able of just download the sample app from the market: [Sample App (requires at least Android 1.6)](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the code to a library, and add the library to your project.

To do this in Eclipse create a new project, using the same package name as the github project (so com.markupartist.android.widget). In the properties select the project to be a library under the Java Build Path tab. Then, in your project, go to its properties, and select the library.

Answer (score 0):

I think your including files are missing (JAR libs) , Click on error icon and then select fix project setup.

Comment: right click on project -->Properties -->Java build patch ---> Libraries tab

Comment: Sorry i dowload project on internet... this project have only one file in src folder (Activity).

Answer (score 0):

I spent around 10  hours trying to fix this problem. All the above ans does not work. Actually what is missing is android support library. To fix this, right click on project, >Android Tool> Add Support Library. Hope this save alot of time for other who came across this. just add support library both on your ActionBar library and the current project.